# Path enumeration counter

Tags: mysql, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

My website has a comment system, and the comments are stored in a table that looks like the following:

```
post_id |  path  | total_replies
   1        1/          3
   2       1/2/         2
   3      1/2/3/        1
   4     1/2/3/4/       0
```

In words, **post id 2** is a reply to **post id 1**, **post id 3** is a reply to **post id 2** which is a reply to **post id 1**, etc. It's literally just a path.

The total_replies column for **post id 1** is `3` because there are 3 replies made to it (post id 2, 3, and 4), and the same logic is used for the other rows.

Because this is a comment system, more rows are added each time a new comment is made. What I'm trying to do is find a way to increment the total_replies column each time a new column is made.

So for example, if someone made a new reply (with **post id 5**) to **post id 2**, the table would look something like this:

```
post_id |  path  | total_replies
   1        1/          4 (this was incremented)
   2       1/2/         3 (this was incremented)
   3      1/2/3/        1
   4     1/2/3/4/       0
   5      1/2/5/        0
```

So, my question is, how would I do the incrementing each time a new reply is made?

***EDIT***: My current query.

```
$stmt = $cxn->prepare("UPDATE posts SET total_replies = total_replies+1 WHERE ? LIKE concat(?, '%') AND post_path != ?");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $new_path, $path, $new_path);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: That doesn't seem like a very good way to store heirarchical data. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want with a `update` and `where` clause:

```
update comments
    set total_replies = total_replies + 1
    where NEWPATH like concat(path, '%');
```

In this case, NEWPATH would be `'1/2/5/'`.  It is unclear whether you have this in a variable or only as a new row in the table.  This assumes that you have it as a variable.

EDIT:

If you do not want to update the original record:

```
update comments
    set total_replies = total_replies + 1
    where NEWPATH like concat(path, '%') and NEWPATH <> path;
```

Comment: However, the problem is that I'm incrementing the total_replies count for all of the paths related to the new one. So, for example, we just added `1/2/5/`. That would increment the total_replies of `1/2/` and `1/` because they are all replies under each other (`5` is a reply to `2` which is a reply to `1`). Would this mean that a loop would be needed to go through the numerical values `1/2/` and increment them like that?

Comment: The statement will update `'1/'`, `'1/2/'`, and `'1/2/5'` as one statement.  To eliminate the last update, add ` and path <> NEWPATH` in the `where` clause.

Comment: What do you mean by adding ` and <>? I'm unfamiliar with more complex queries.

Comment: I've actually also found another issue. Say perhaps we are replying to the following path: `1/2/` (and the id will be `4` for the new reply). This means that the new path will be `1/2/4/`. However, if the path `1/2/3/` exists in the database, your query will also increment the total replies of that row. Rather, it should only update `1/2/` and `1/2/4/`.

Comment: @Bagwell . . . The query will not increment `'1/2/3'` in that case.

Comment: Ah, it was my misunderstanding with my variables. I got it working. Thanks a bunch! :)